# Unity Gaming Error - This message parameter has to be of type collider

Tags: c#

I am currently programming a game in Unity3d but I have some problems. I'm doing a Animal information game. So for example. If I go near an animal it will trigger a dialog box (using `onTriggerEnter`) where it will be shown some information. This information will be shown in 2 pages.

My problem now is that when i write the code in the console i get an error

> This message parameter has to be of type collider.

Now I get it that `onTriggerEnter` has to be of type collider but I need also the parameter bool clicked. I don't know how to solve it.
My Script:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(bool clicked)
{
    if (gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        dialogboxFirstPage.SetActive(true);
        dialogboxSecondPage.SetActive(false);
        nextPageButton.SetActive(true);
        dialogtextFirstPage.text = "Some text";
        //dialogtextSecondPage.text = "";
        Debug.Log("OnTriggerEnter");
    }
    else
    {
        if(gameObject.tag == "Player" && clicked == true)
        {
            dialogboxFirstPage.SetActive(false);
            dialogboxSecondPage.SetActive(true);
            nextPageButton.SetActive(true);
            //dialogtextFirstPage.text = " ";
            dialogtextSecondPage.text = "dfdfdfd";
        }
    }
```

Comment: **NB**: This condition `if(gameObject.tag == "Player" && clicked == true)` will never be true

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, OnTriggerEnter takes a parameter (Collider other). You have to use that parameter.

In addition, since when you enter the trigger, the collider will always belong to the player, you will never hit that else block. You need to check if clicked is true inside the "if tag is Player".

Lastly, you can still use the bool. Since you set clicked to be true or false elsewhere, you don't need to pass it as a parameter anyway in order to check its value.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        if (!clicked)
        {
            dialogboxFirstPage.SetActive(true);
            dialogboxSecondPage.SetActive(false);
            nextPageButton.SetActive(true);
            dialogtextFirstPage.text = "Some text";
            Debug.Log("OnTriggerEnter");
        }
        else
        {
            dialogboxFirstPage.SetActive(false);
            dialogboxSecondPage.SetActive(true);
            nextPageButton.SetActive(true);
            dialogtextFirstPage.text = "dfdfdfd";
            Debug.Log("OnTriggerEnter");
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this sets you on the right track and helps you to make a great animal game.

Comment: thnx for the comment :) but i have used a want to use a button to go from the first page to the second page. I dont click the "player" i click the next button

Comment: I've just realised that my code actually doesn't work. You would need to check whether or not the button would be clicked in a separate function, OnTriggerStay, because with OnTriggerEnter, it would only change if you left the trigger box and entered it again.

Answer (score 0):

That api does not take a bool parameter. You will have to be more specific on what you are trying to accomplish. If you need to retrieve the state of the mouse the following code will do it. Take what you need from it.

**EDIT**: You must be new to C#, C# is strongly typed, meaning the spec of the api you are calling STRICTLY accepts only the parameters it advertises.

See [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html)

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        Debug.Log("Pressed left click.");

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        Debug.Log("Pressed right click.");

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
        Debug.Log("Pressed middle click.");
```